# Access to global array of structures in C

Tags: c

**The problem in short**

I update global array of structures in one file (`add_product.c`), but can't print these updates out in another file (`show_list.c`).

**Details**

If you need a full image, look at [github repo](https://github.com/Antekirta/c_products-list/tree/master/src)

Here is the essence.

The program I write let user does the following:

1. Create a list of products
2. Add a product on existing list
3. Show all the products on the list

... and consists of 4 files:

- `global-variables.h`
- `main.c`
- `show_list.c`
- `add_product.c`

`global-variables.h`

```c
#define LIST_OF_PRODUCTS_INITIAL_LENGTH 50

struct Product {
    char name[50];
    float price;
    unsigned int amount;
};

extern struct Product *list_of_products[LIST_OF_PRODUCTS_INITIAL_LENGTH];
extern unsigned int current_list_of_products_length;
```

`main.c`

```c
struct Product *list_of_products[LIST_OF_PRODUCTS_INITIAL_LENGTH];
unsigned int current_list_of_products_length = 0;

add_product();

show_list();
```

`add_product.c`

```c
int add_product() {
    ...

    struct Product new_product;

    list_of_products[current_list_of_products_length] = &new_product;

    current_list_of_products_length++;

    // For example, cheese
    scanf("%s", &list_of_products[current_list_of_products_length]->name);
    fflush(stdin);

    scanf("%f", &list_of_products[current_list_of_products_length]->price);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("Enter the amount of %s: ", list_of_products[current_list_of_products_length]->name);
    scanf("%d", &list_of_products[current_list_of_products_length]->amount);
    fflush(stdin);

    list_of_products_exists = true;

    // **NOTICE**! All the values here are printed correctly (cheese  15    150)
    printf("Name: %s \n", list_of_products[current_list_of_products_length]->name);
    printf("Price: %.2f\n", list_of_products[current_list_of_products_length]->price);
    printf("Amount: %d\n", list_of_products[current_list_of_products_length]->amount);

    ...
};
```

`show_list.c` **THE PROBLEM IS HERE!**

```c
int show_list() {
    ...
    
    current_product = *list_of_products[0];

    // EXPECTED cheese  15    150
    // ACTUAL   @6є     0     0.00
    printf("%10s %10d %10.2f", current_product.name, current_product.amount, current_product.price);

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    struct Product new_product;

    list_of_products[current_list_of_products_length] = &new_product;
```

is bad because `new_product` is local to this block and not static, so this will be invalidated when rethrning from the function and the pointer become useless.

You should allocate memory dynamically like this instead:

```
    list_of_products[current_list_of_products_length] = malloc(sizeof(struct Product));
```

---

Also this line invokes *undefined behavior* by type mismatch and the `&` should be removed.

```
    scanf("%s", &list_of_products[current_list_of_products_length]->name);
```

Also `fflush(stdin);` [invokes *undefined behavior*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin), so you shouldn't use that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helped (the same as the one below), but here is just a small addition: ```list_of_products[current_list_of_products_length] = (struct Product *)malloc(sizeof(struct Product));```

Answer (score 1):

Doing this inside a function:

```
struct Product new_product;
list_of_products[current_list_of_products_length] = &new_product;
...
```

Yields undefined behavior once you're outside of the function.

This is because the local variable `new_product` is no longer viable at this point, hence it is undetermined what resides at the address `&new_product` (where this variable was allocated during the execution of the function).